# How do you to use an input with map and filter in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have two functions replaceEmptyStr and  nonEmptyStr.

For replaceEmptyStr I want to use a map to replace blank strings in my input with -1s

```
["2", "", "4", ""] -> ["2", "-1", "4", "-1"]
```

For nonEmptyStr I want to filter out the blank spaces in my input

```
["2", "", "3"] -> ["2", "3"]
```

This is my code for both functions

```
replaceEmptyStr :: String -> String
replaceEmptyStr x = map ["-1"][""]

nonEmptyStr :: String -> Bool
nonEmptyStr x =  filter (" ") nonEmptyStr x
```

```
   assignment3.hs:32:16:
    Illegal type signature: ‘String -> Bool nonEmptyStr x’
      Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables
    In a pattern type-signature

assignment3.hs:34:44: Not in scope: ‘x’

assignment3.hs:37:20:
    Illegal type signature: ‘String -> String replaceEmptyStr x’
      Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables
    In a pattern type-signature
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I don't understand why this isn't working but in other examples online through the GCHI people were able to call it without the input.  Why doesn't this work with the input involved?

Edit:

Fixed the error with Not in Scope "x" for nonEmptyStr by removing the x and the call to nonEmptyStr but it still says

assignment3.hs:32:16:

Illegal type signature: ‘String -> Bool nonEmptyStr x’

Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables

In a pattern type-signature

assignment3.hs:36:20:

Illegal type signature: ‘String -> String replaceEmptyStr x’

Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables

In a pattern type-signature

Edit :

```
nonEmptyStr :: String -> Bool

nonEmptyStr x =  filter (" ")
```

-- 6

```
replaceEmptyStr :: String -> String

replaceEmptyStr x = map ["-1"][""]
```

Comment: @duplode what do you mean by missing line breaks?

Comment: That you might have put the signature and the definition in the same line.

Comment: @duplode What do you mean by signature and definition in same line?  See Edit

Comment: Compare the code you are running with the code you have posted here. Are they exactly the same? (If not, and if comparing them doesn't show what is wrong, please [edit] your question so that the code here is *exactly* what you are trying to run.)

Comment: @duplode edit above

Comment: The code you have added still does not produce the error message in your question. (Code-Apprentice's answer addresses the code as posted here, and not the error.)

Answer (score 1):

In GHCi, you can use the `:t` command to get the type of an object. Let's try this for `map`:

```
Prelude> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This tells us that `map` takes two parameters. The first has type `(a -> b)` which  is a function. The second has type `[a]` which is a list. The return value has type `[b]` which is also a list. The letters show us that the function given as the first parameter must take an argument with the same type as the elements of the list given as the second parameter. The return type of this function is the same as the elements of the list returned by `map`.

Now with that information, we can see why `map ["-1"][""]` is incorrect. This is trying to pass two lists to `map`. So how do we fix this?

Well, we need a function that takes an element from the input list and returns an element of the output list. So given a **single** element of the input, how do you create the correct corresponding element in the output? I leave this as an exercise to the reader. (Hint: You can do it with an `if...else` expression.)

Once you figure out this function, you pass the input list from `replaceEmptyString` directly as the second parameter of `map`.

You should use `:t filter` to see what the signature for this function is. Then you can break down the solution in the same way as we did here for `map`.

Comment: What would I even put for (a -> b) as a function.  Do I make a type defintion then make a new function

Comment: replaceEmptyStr :: String -> String
 
   
  replaceEmptyStr = ""
  replaceEmpty1 = "-1" 
  
  replaceEmptyStr x = map replaceEmpty1 x                                                                                This didn't work but I don't know what you mean by using if and else with map

Comment: @MartinVadakara Okay, let's back up a minute then. You need a **function** to use with `map`. That function takes an element from the input list and returns a single element for the output list. Can you describe in words what this function should do? How does it decide the result for the corresponding element in the output?

Comment: I know that a function is f * g that sort of from math.  But I'm not sure what exactly I'm supposed to do to get (a -> b) part of the equation

Comment: @MartinVadakara what is the type of an element of your input list?

Answer (score 0):

## Currying

First off, if you want to use currying to write in a pointfree style (which is a good thing, if you ask me), you must remove the argument after the function name

Instead of writing

```
sum numbers = foldl1 (+) numbers
```

you would write

```
sum = foldl1 (+)
```

But not

```
sum numbers = foldl1 (+)
```

## Function arguments

The first arguments to `map` and `filter` need to be functions. The elements of the list that will be the second argument to them will be applied to those functions.

Either you define a function somewhere else and pass it to `map`/`filter`:

```
greaterThanTwo x = 2 < x
removeSmallNumbers = filter greaterThanTwo
```

or you use currying to create an anonymous function in-place:

```
removeSmallNumbers = filter ((<) 2)
```

`(" ")` isn't a function that returns False when passed an empty string, it is just a string containing a single space.

(BTW, do you want to remove empty strings or to remove strings containing a single space? Your example at the beginning points to the former…).

Comment: I want to remove empty strings

Comment: It's obviously an assignment, so I won't just do your homework for you.

Comment: Thank for your answer.  It was for an assignment which I should have clarified.  I was kind of freaking out yesterday.